# Getting Invalid mapping expression specified when setting GatewayResponse

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

The default API Gateway responses come in this form: `{"message":$context.error.messageString}`.
Changing this template via the console, to add wrap it in an `"error"` object for example, works fine. However, when I try it in CDK, it errors during deployment with `Invalid mapping expression specified`

**Code** (*notice this is literally the default template*):

```js
webServiceApi.addGatewayResponse('4XX', {
   type: apigw.ResponseType.DEFAULT_4XX,
   responseHeaders: COMMON_HEADERS,
   templates: {
      'application/json': '{"message":$context.error.messageString}',
   },
});
```

This happens with any change as well including all the AWS-written examples I could find. It's under-documented everywhere in AWS: CDK, SDK, API Gateway and CloudFormation so it's very difficult for me to figure out what's wrong there?

**CloudFormation Error**

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: *] (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: [TRUNCATED], Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: [TRUNCATED], HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Answer (score 6):

Apparantly the error was not with the mapping template, it was the headers needed to `"'*'"` for the origin instead of `"*"`. That is NOT a useful error message

Comment: This is exactly right. I believe it's actually a VTL expression, so you'd have to quote the literal response. But it does mean you can use other VTL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the OP, this error is very misleading and indicates a syntax error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED: RootMethod (AWS::ApiGateway::Method)
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: true] 
(Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: <snip>; Proxy: null)
```

For me it was the difference between `'true'` and `"'true'"`

`method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "'true'"`